# OData PHP Producer

Tags: php, web-services, odata

I need to create a PHP OData producer supporting both GET and PUT. Up to now I've only found [this library](http://odataphpproducer.codeplex.com/), unfortunately this not support PUT operation.
Any suggestions?
Thank's

Comment: I guess you should read meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no PHP Library (public) available to support OData CUD (Change, Update and Delete) operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just released. Documentation is coming.

https://packagist.org/packages/falseclock/dbd-php

```
    $cache = DBD\Cache\MemCache::me()->create(array(['host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211]),false,"15 min")->open();

    $odata_options = array(
        'RaiseError'        => true,
        'PrintError'        => true,
        'HTMLError'         => true,
        'CacheDriver'       => $cache
    );

    $od = (new DBD\OData())->create('http://crm.beta.virtex.kz/odata/', "user", "password", $odata_options);

    $sth = $od->prepare("
        SELECT 
            Ref_Key, Number, Date
        FROM 
            Document_Invoices 
        ORDER BY
            Date аsc
        LIMIT 10
    ");
    $sth->cache('CacheKey','24h'); 
    $sth->execute();

    while ($row = $sth->fetchrow()) {
        print_r($row);
    }

$od->update(
    'Document_Invoices',
    array('Date' => $data['Date']),
    "(guid?)",
    $data['Ref_Key'] // for ?-placeholder
);
```